# Why all oracle processes are reading /proc/<pid>/cmdline of multiple system processes?

Tags: background-process, lsof, oracle-database

I am exploring oracle processes and it's lsof output. I am wondering what is `/proc/<pid>/cmdline`. 145 same cmdline openfiles displayed for each process of oracle.

So what exactly is this?

Eg:

```
#lsof -u oracle | grep cmdline
oracle   2664 oracle   17r   REG                0,3         0   9492 /proc/1/cmdline
oracle   2664 oracle   18r   REG                0,3         0   9495 /proc/2/cmdline
.
.
.
oracle  12586 oracle  160r   REG                0,3         0  20528 /proc/2614/cmdline
oracle  12586 oracle  161r   REG                0,3         0  20529 /proc/2662/cmdline



# lsof -u oracle | grep cmdline | awk '{print $2}' | sort | uniq -c
145 12297
145 2664
145 2666
145 2670
145 2672
145 2674
145 2676
145 2678
145 2680
145 2682
145 2684
145 2686
145 2688
145 2690
145 2692
145 2694
145 2696
145 2698
145 2700
145 2702
145 2775
145 2777
145 2795
145 2799
145 2900
145 6323
```

Comment: If you actually meant to ask _Why do all of these oracle processes each have 145 open file descriptors to seemingly every `/proc/x/cmdline` file?_ then your question needs to be [edit]ed to _actually ask that_.  Otherwise you are just asking what the file is, and as you can see by what you have got already, answers will _not address_ what oracle is doing at all.

Comment: yes, I have changed my question now.

Comment: It seems like Oracle is doing something equivalent to running `ps` internally.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the manpages for `proc(5)`:

> /proc/[pid]/cmdline
>
> This read-only file holds the complete command line for the
> process, unless the process is a zombie.  In the latter case,
> there is nothing in this file: that is, a read on this file
> will return 0 characters.  The command-line arguments appear
> in this file as a set of strings separated by null bytes
> ('\0'), with a further null byte after the last string.

Comment: What is meant by command line for the process? And why it would be useful anywhere or in the oracle example I mentioned?

Comment: As stated, the file exposes the *command* and any associated *arguments* used to start a process.  This can be useful in assessing what's actually running.

Comment: Why would Oracle be looking at the command lines of totally unrelated processes? It has `/proc/1/cmdline` open, that's the `init` process.

Comment: Yes, that could be..anyhow I thought it might be of something of importance at the time I have put this question..but now it certainly not.